# Android ProgressDialog dismiss. Detect source

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I currently have an `AsyncTask` that has a `ProgressDialog` in it. I set the `OnDismissListener` by `setOnDismissListener`, and then I cancel the `AsyncTask`. The thing is, that the `ProgressDialog` (and subsequently the `AsyncTask`) get dismissed whether I press the back button or anywhere in the screen.

I would like to reach a point where I know how the `ProgressDialog` was dismissed, and then if the back button was pressed I will cancel the `AsyncTask`, and if the area outside the `ProgressDialog` was pressed, I will just minimize the `ProgressDialog` but the `AsyncTask` will continue.

How do I detect what set of the `OnDismissListener`? Is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Edit (based on the comments bellow):

This is my code. I placed a breakpoint inside both listeners, and now matter how I cancel the dialog (back button or outside the dialog), both listeners are called.

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.show();

        mProgressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                (SyncOperation.this).cancel(true);
            }

        });

        mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new ProgressDialog.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                (SyncOperation.this).cancel(true);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: the are 2 listeners, onDismiss, and onCancel

Comment: The description is not sufficient its better to post some relevant code also.

Comment: Both the listeners are called when either one of the mentioned operations is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a private variable:

```
private boolean mBackPressed;
```

And then I implemented to listeners as follows:

```
mProgressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            (SyncOperation.this).cancel(true);
            if(mBackPressed) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mBackPressed = false;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Minimize", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });

    mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new ProgressDialog.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                mBackPressed = true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleGestureDetector

```
detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
```

Comment: Is this not a workaround way to do this? The dialog gets cancelled whether I press back or on the screen, I just want to change what happens each time...